# I have formula in a NSString... How to evaluate it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a fast C or Objective-C math parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892152/what-is-a-fast-c-or-objective-c-math-parser)

I have a create a function which takes a formula as a NSString. And I have to replace few things in the String and get the value after executing the formula. How can I do this...

Ex: NSString *formulaString = @"((A/B)-1)*100";

Now I can replace A by 20, and B by 10.
But how will get calculated value that is ((20/10)-1)*100 as 100

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809927/objective-c-how-to-convert-a-string-with-mathematical-expressions-into-a-float?lq=1

Comment: This is where you put to use all that stuff about parsing you were supposed to have learned in the classes you slept through this summer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the characters by this method

```
NSString *formulaString = @"((A/B)-1)*100";

NSString *modifiedFormulaString = [formulaString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"A" withString:@"10"];

modifiedFormulaString = [modifiedFormulaString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"B" withString:@"10"];
```

But to calculate dat u need to parse it using some parser.

Answer (score 8):

You have to build expression calculator. An open source objective C library I am aware of is [GCMathParser](http://www.apptree.net/parser.htm)

Comment: Also noteworthy is the excellent [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) library.

Comment: @MSK whether GCMathParser is for cocoa or cocoa touch?

Answer (score 6):

If your formula is not too complicated, you can use `NSExpression`:

```
NSExpression *e = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"((20/10)-1)*100"];
NSNumber *result = [e expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
// Output: 100
```

This works even with some functions such as `sqrt`, `exp`, ... See the `NSExpression` documentation for a list of supported function.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write a mathematical expression parser that takes a `NSString *` input and yields a numerical output.