# can I convert + as an NSString to addition operator directly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios4, nsstring

I have a mathematical equation in string format.

Is there a way to convert @"+"(String constant) directly to addition operator in objective C
Or

I have to use If-Else statements to solve this equation  ??

Comment: What's the particular use case that you're inquiring about this for? Ie why do you want to do this?

Comment: 123+456+678-985 it is in the form of a string constant. can I convert it into mathematical equation like (float I=123+456+678-985)

Comment: If it's just @"+" just compare strings. If you actually want to evaluate expressions, then I suggest look for an open source implementation of string equations.

Comment: yes, of course. comparing with IF-ELSE work fine, but I wasn't worried about that. I just wanted to know if there is a way to convert this directly..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSPredicate * parsed = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"123+456+678-985 = 0"];
NSExpression * left = [(NSComparisonPredicate *)parsed leftExpression];
NSNumber * result = [left expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
float i = [result floatValue];
```

Comment: You don't need the predicate, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12500232/i-have-formula-in-a-nsstring-how-to-evaluate-it/12500518#12500518.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([yourString isEqualToString:@"+"])
{
     //Do something

}
```

This code should work.

Comment: yes, of course. this work fine
but I wasn't worried about that
just wanted to know if there is a way to convert is directly..:)

Comment: Remember the check :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSExpression to achieve this

```
NSString *expressionFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%d %@ %d)",firstNumber,arcthimaticOperator,secondNumber];
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:expressionFormat];
NSNumber *result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", result);
```

Please make sure you enter the correct format else the above code will throw exception.