# convert an array of string values to use as a formulas

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to coding and objective C so thanks for the help in advance.

I have a .plist file containing an array of strings filled with formulas such as

*5.3

/2

-10.5

I am able to retrieve these string values from the .plist file but I am getting a little stuck trying to append these string formulas to existing variables with the hopes of returning a converted number. For example I would like to use my variable 7 with the formula *5.3 and return 37.1
7 *5.3 -> 37.1

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appending the string to a variable is straightforward; it can be accomplished with something like this:

```
NSString *equation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@", variable, plistEntry];
```

You'll run into problems when you want to evaluate this equation, however. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809655/math-expression-evaluation-very-fast-with-objective-c) SO question discusses expression evaluation in Objective-C. Dave DeLong's answer links to a couple of libraries that you may want to look into: [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) and [GCMathParser](http://apptree.net/parser.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This can't be done as-is. You'll need one of the many free expression evaluators (probably in C) that float around on the web.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6809655/math-expression-evaluation-very-fast-with-objective-c).