# Evaluate math expression in string? (NSString)

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is a fast C or Objective-C math parser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892152/what-is-a-fast-c-or-objective-c-math-parser)

I have a NSString which represents a calculation eg. `@"(10+10)*2"` and I want to evaluate the string as if it was actually something like this;

```
double result = (10+10)*2;
```

What is the most straightforward approach to take in iOS?

Comment: Do you mind calling out to another application?  `bc` could handle that without much trouble.

Comment: It would implemented on iOS so probably would need to be self contained ?

Comment: You have a [cocoa] tag - you should probably retag appropriately, then.

Comment: 1. Tokenise the input using a lexer. 2. Parse the resulting tokens, build an AST. 3. Evaluate the AST recursively. 4. ???? 5. Profit!

Comment: have you try use `doubleValue`? is it working?

Comment: @Itai Ferber: Thanks, Looks like what I need - I'll try them out.

Comment: [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser) worked for me on iOS 5 with no problems. Thanks All.

Comment: you can also do as : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14436004/arithmetic-operators-and-key-value-coding/14436391#14436391

Comment: I would recommend the C library [TinyExpr](https://github.com/codeplea/tinyexpr).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at Dave DeLong's [DDMathParser framework](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser).

Comment: Thanks. @itai-ferber already pointed to duplicate question which suggests DDMathParser as solution (see comment thread above)... so I already have this working.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [GCMathParser](http://apptree.net/parser.htm).

Comment: This worked out of the box in OS X but I'm having some difficulty getting this to work with iOS 5... It appears to need a little more tweaking that just replacing "#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>" with "#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>" - I'll look at it again after I check the other suggestions. Thanks.