# Type-out Calculator? Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Not exactly sure what it would be called?

But anyway, I am wondering how exactly one would make a calculator where the user types his equation into a text box, and then when the user hits "=" it calculates everything the user has typed in.

ex. user types:
1 + 1 * (1 +2)
*hits enter*
6 (is displayed)

-EDIT- I screwed up on my math :P
4 (is displayed)

I couldn't find any articles talking about this on the internet, for I didn't really know what to search for. So if anyone could help, or at least point me in the right direction. It would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: You need to ask as **specific** question.  What are you having trouble with?  Creating a GUI?  Parsing the user input?  Performing the calculation?  etc.

Comment: NSExpression Is what you want, as far as I can tell from the docs. No need for a 3rd party library here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called math parsers.

There are two very good libraries that are freely available:  DDMathParser and GCMathParser.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9651333/937822) for more details.

They are **much** more capable than NSExpression.

Comment: DDMathParser is the method I am using now. It is simple to use and works amazingly. Also it is free: check out the wiki here for all question concerning it: https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser/wiki/Usage

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is something with `NSExpression` I think:

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:inputText, nil];
NSNumber *result = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil];
```

I have tested NSExpression with mathematical symbols (`0-9`, `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `(`, `)`) and it seems to work as expected. Give it a shot, it may just work for you.

Comment: Thanks I think this is exactly what I'm looking for, I'll try it out. Then let you know

Comment: This is really awesome, but the `+ expressionWithFormat` isn't documented in the NSExpression Class Reference.  Is there any info on how it works (or is it a private class)?

Comment: @Inafziger no, it isn't a private method, but god only knows why apple doesn't have it documented in the latest version of their docs. It used to be documented, but I'm not sure why it wouldn't be anymore.

Comment: Very strange!  Great functionality though!

Answer (score 1):

You might try looking up "infix notation" and "parse trees" as a start.

Answer (score 1):

```
1 + 1 * (1 +2) hits enter 6 (is displayed)
```

hmm, i'm sure there're lot of samples of human math, but 1 + 1x(1+2) != 6 :)

One recommendation from me would be to collect all unrecognized character-groups and consider it to be variables, then let a user to enter the values. Like 1 + y*(1+z), enter, y=1, z=2, enter, result=4.