# Obj-C from string to float (Math)

Tags: objective-c, string, math

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluate math expression in string? (NSString)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651333/evaluate-math-expression-in-string-nsstring)

Hey i have got this string but how can i make it to at float equation.

```
5+5*10+(5*2 + sinf(1))
```

how can i calculate this piece from a string.

```
NSString *stringvalue = @"5+5*10+(5*2 + sinf(1))";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4892194/846273) you can either use [GCMathParser](http://apptree.net/parser.htm) or [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser).

Comment: Instead of posting a link to a duplicate question, vote to close this one as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: sorry I though I did not have the privilege. Done.