# How to output math from a text field? Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, math, field, textfield, calculator

I'm very new to Xcode so excuse my unintelligence. I have an app with a text field and a button. What I am trying to achieve is inputting math into the text field, such as 2+2, and pressing the button to receive the answer, which would be 4.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Evaluate math expression in string? (NSString)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9651333/evaluate-math-expression-in-string-nsstring)

Comment: Also, for the lulz, you could do this: `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [_resultLabel setText:
     [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:
      [[@"eval('" stringByAppendingString:textField.text]
       stringByAppendingString:@"')"]]];
    return YES;
}` where textField is the field the user enters into for which your UIViewController is a delegate, and _webView is a hidden UIWebView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `NSExpression` which lets you do things such as:

```
NSExpression *expression = [NSExpression expressionWithFormat:@"4 + 5 - 2*3"];
id value = [expression expressionValueWithObject:nil context:nil]; // => 3
```

**References**

- [NSExpression Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSExpression_Class/index.html)
- [NSExpression on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsexpression/)