# Can you evaluate the contents of an NSString and get the BOOL value of the evaluated expression?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, boolean-expression

In Objective-C, say you have an `NSString` containing the following:

```
NSString * boolStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", "1 > 0"];
```

Is there a way to evaluate the NSString and get the boolean value of the string's contents?

Comment: Side note - Why are you using `stringWithFormat:`? Just do `NSString * boolStr = @"1 > 0";`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a fast C or Objective-C math parser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892152/what-is-a-fast-c-or-objective-c-math-parser)

Comment: That solution appears to use a non-standard library.  I'm hoping to achieve this without having to include any non-standards.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I assume you want to evaluate an actual expression. For simple expressions you can abuse NSPredicate to do that, example:

```
    NSPredicate *predicate1=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"1>0"];
    NSPredicate *predicate2=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"1<0"];

    BOOL    ok1=[predicate1 evaluateWithObject:nil];
    BOOL    ok2=[predicate2 evaluateWithObject:nil];

    NSLog(@"ok1: %d  ok2: %d",ok1,ok2);
```

This will print: `ok1: 1  ok2: 0`

Comment: Thank Gerd, I think this is the way to go.  Your example works fine but when I try to add my (somewhat more complicated) expression I get runtime errors.  I'll continue to debug.  Thanks!

Comment: NSPredicate doesn't seem to work with complex expressions (ie "[SomeSingleton].var >= [SomeOtherSingleton].var"), I'm having to adjust my approach.  Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Wouldn't `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%@>=%@",obj1.var,obj2.var]` do the trick?

Comment: For some reason it's always evaluating to "YES" when I do it with the NSPredicate.  When I evaluate the exact same expression normally it evaluates properly.