# How to allow equations in UITextFields?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UITextField in my app that I want users to be able to enter equations into. These equations can vary from something as simple as `2+2` to something as crazy as `(((4^2) + (6^3)) / 2) * (100 - 14)` but no matter how it's formatted, it should always work.

The equation needs to follow order of operations, as well as return the right answer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into a math parser, such as [DDMathParser](https://github.com/davedelong/DDMathParser).

For more, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892152/what-is-a-fast-c-or-objective-c-math-parser).

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been implemented and it's incredible!